# need to negotiate a leaving date, but I have no negotiation skills

Tags: job-change, negotiation

the situation in a nutshell:

- in my current company, I'm finishing the huge project with a lot of visibility
- I got a job offer from other company and I accepted it
- the other company wants me for start there ASAP (but I told them that I needed the leaving period done at actual company)
- the actual company wants me to stay for the whole leaving period (25 days)

I want to finish the project and move on, but the new company is pressing upon me.

how could I negotiate it with the other company?

Comment: yes it is. there is a lot of legalese, but it is indeed.

Comment: Point out to them that you they can;t trust you to honor your contract with them if you wil break the contract you have with your current employer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to negotiate. If you have a contractual obligation to your existing employer and you've disclosed your non-standard departure length to your new employer, the new employer should respect you and your professional responsibility.  Anything less and, personally, I'd question the quality and professionalism of the new employer.

Comment: I sometimes find helpful saying a variation of "I need to respect the contract I signed with my current employer. I'm sure you'd want me to do the same for you."

Answer (score -4):

You worked and got paid for your work. You don't owe them anything. If you are definitely leaving to go to the new job just do. A 25 Day leaving period is ridiculous regardless of what you do... You don't owe the other company anything regardless of any personal connections or friendships you may have with anyone.

Comment: You owe them what is stated in the contract. If the contract says "25 days leaving period", behaving professionally includes honoring that. It is not ridiculous by the way. In Europe it may even be a legal minimum. You cannot just hire and fire people at will here.

Comment: OP says nothing about a contract or being in Europe.

Comment: He is talking about a "leaving period", where else but in a contract would that be found? And as he did not say where he is from, calling his leaving period "ridiculous" is just wrong. It may be where you are from, but this is an international site. If it's in his contract, chances are it's not ridiculous where he is from.

Comment: Employee handbook or de facto rule.